# Developing an app using Django. Do I design front-end after app? Or develop Django to fit UI?

Tags: web-development, python, web-applications, django, python-3.x

Edit: this differs from a similar question because I'm interested specifically in how Django works with the front-end. I.e. what is considered best practice when developing using the Django framework.

I am learning Python at university and need to produce an implementation project.  I'd like to write a web application using Python with the Django web framework.

I've been learning as much HTML, CSS and Javascript as possible so I know what's going on at the front-end.

I've found some nice designs on Codepen which would be useful in what I'm designing, but can I use them and design a Django app around it?  Or do I need to get the back-end together first and then design the front-end to fit.

Comment: tl;dr - just pick what appears to be the path of least resistance

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this depends on what your app does, and what are its strong suites. Lets say for the sake of simplicity that your app does one of the 3 things:

1. Combines standard/non-ground-breaking code chunks/practices into a
   cool new way of organizing or viewing data for users (like, "Twitter
   for pets!")
2. Reveals some awesome new technology that you have unique control
   over that differentiates your app from its competitors (like, "Our
   new search engine indexes text from pictures in public Facebook
   pages!"
3. Is just a prototype of other apps that you are using as a learning
   experiment to develop your coding skills, and won't actually be
   commercially viable on its own.

For #1, **you should develop the UI first**, because what you are building isn't earth-shattering in terms of its back-end, it just needs to hook user in with it slick/easy interface. Therefor, the UI is the most important piece and needs to drive the functionality.

For #2, invert the statements in #1. Your UI will prob just be a reflection of what cool new thing you can do in the backend, **so start on the backend first**.

For #3, **it doesn't really matter**, although my personal preference is to work on the UI first.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. My app will largely integrate other services within my platform, so I think I'll go with the UI side first like your first suggestion and add my own functionality as the project develops.